# Character table of quaternions $Q_8$

Tags: representation-theory, quaternions, characters

I wanted to compute the character table of the quaternion group Q_8, and to this end I was reading this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1150920/340973). For the degree 1 representation I used [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1398722/340973) but for the degree 2 representation I don't understand how the hint from the first link works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is to map your quaternions to matrices with complex entries of the form $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}z&w\\-\bar{w}&\bar{z}\end{array}\right).$$

This will give you a representation, on $\mathbb{C}^2$, and by taking the traces of the matrices you get the characters.

It is no surprise that the identity $e\in Q_8$ maps to the identity matrix.
So you are left with 3 quaternions, $i,j,k$ that you need to decide where to map to.  Note the space of such matrices is 4 dimensional over the reals, parameterised by the real part of $z$, the imaginary part of $z$, the real part of $w$, and the imaginary part of $w$, from which you get a natural basis.  You already sent $e$ to one of these basis vectors (corresponding to the real part of $z$).  You could try mapping $i,j,k$  to the other three basis vectors.

Remember you need to check that the identities that hold between the elements of $Q_8$ also hold between the matrices you send them to.

---

You also need to decide to do with $-1\in Q_8$ but there is a really obvious candidate for where to send it.  Also it is fixed once you decide where to send $i,j$ or $k$.

Also you may be using the notation $Q_8=\langle x,y|y^2=x^2,xyx=y\rangle$.  In this case by $i$ I mean $x$, by $j$ I mean $y$, by $k$ I mean $xy$ and by $-1$ I mean $y^2$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand. I sent $1\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$, $-1\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0\\0 &-1 \end{bmatrix}$, $i\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} i & 0\\0 &-i \end{bmatrix}$, $j\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\-1 &0 \end{bmatrix}$, $k\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 0 & i\\i &0 \end{bmatrix}$. But why is this a irreducible representation?

Comment: Spot on with the matrices.  Note they do not commute (e.g. $ij\neq ji$).  If the representation broke down into two $1$ dimensional representations, then they would each factor through the abelianization of $Q_8$.

Comment: I'm am not sure I understand. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: Any $1$ dimensional complex representation of a group $G$, is a map  $G\to \mathbb{C}$. Thus the direct sum of two $1$ dimensional representations will map $G$ to diagonal matrices.  However diagonal matrices commute and the matrices that you found do not.  Thus the representation you found cannot be the sum of two $1$ dimensional representations.  Note that picking a different basis could mean the matrices are no longer diagonal.  However the property of commuting is independent of choice of basis.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I thought it was something to do with a map : $Q_8/[Q_8,Q_8]\to Gl(V)$ but I didn't get it

Comment: You could phrase it that way, but no need to you prefer not to.